# Pipe a file into grep and perform grep search with regex

Tags: bash, grep

**Background:**

I have the following list of keywords in keywords.txt:

```
animal
building
person
```

and the following list of fake users and passwords in users.txt:

```
user:animal@234
user2:animal234
user3:animal
```

I'd like to use grep to correlate the two files (i.e. search for an *exact* occurrence of each keyword in users.txt)

My first attempt ...

```
cat keywords.txt | grep -F -w -f- users.txt
```

returned

```
user:animal@234
user3:animal
```

because `grep -w` will return lines in which the keyword is "followed a by non-word constituent character." Hence user:animal@234 was returned because the keyword "animal" followed by the non-word constituent character '@' was found.

I did some searching and found that `grep ":animal$" users.txt` returned the desired result:

```
user3:animal
```

because '$' is the regex symbol for end-of-line.

**Problem:**

I'm having trouble implementing a solution to search for all keywords, instead of just "animal."

Here's what I have so far:

```
while read line; do echo -n ":${line}$" | grep -F -f- users.txt; done < keywords.txt
```

Unfortunately, ^ this command returns nothing. It should return:

```
user3:animal
```

Any thoughts on what I should try?

Comment: `awk -F: 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next}$2 in a' keywords users`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `awk`:

```
awk -F: 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a' keywords.txt users.txt

user3:animal
```